# Chrome rendering asp.net block

Tags: asp.net, css, google-chrome, html, updatepanel

I have a page in asp.net that does not render correctly in Chrome:  when a certain block becomes smaller (because of the number of the elements of a grid on the page) the background does not get entirely refreshed, it leaves a part fom the previous rendering, until changing the tab browser and returning back. Same thing happens when going through blocks that become visible and then hidden. Is there a way to force a re-render of the background (I'm using UpdatePanel and Chrome v 24.0.1)? Or has anyone seen this behaviour and managed to solve this (could it be some z-index css problem)? Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of researching the asp code, the properties of the grid, the css, the foums on chrome bugs, it seems that a css property modification of the div underneath the grid did the trick, I had to change overflow: visible to overflow: hidden.